# How to get XML File parsed from Google Drive without sharing the Link globaly

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I'm building a XML parser in Google App Script, witch gets XMLs from Google Drive. At the moment i could only get it to work, when the link of the XML file is shared global.

```
   function XmlChecker(FileID){ 
     var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + FileID + "&export=download").getContentText();
     var xml = XmlService.parse(data);
     var root = xml.getRootElement();
     
     var namespace = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/short');
```

- Is there a way to get the same result without sharing the link?
- The Google App Scripts is build in a Spreadsheet. Can i give the spreadsheet access via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file of `FileID` is in your Google Drive, how about retrieving the data using Drive service as follows?

#### From:

```
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + FileID + "&export=download").getContentText();
```

#### To:

```
var data = DriveApp.getFileById(FileID).getBlob().getDataAsString();
```

- By this modification, the data can be retrieved from the file of `FileID` without publicly sharing.

#### Reference:

- [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)